# how to check timer is running on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've add timer to display images in my app.

is there any way to check the timer is running or not.?

after checking , the timer should be cancel using timer.cancel() method.

Pls hlp me.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this yourself by recording the timers unique integer and use it later to cancel. I find a useful place to set/cancel this is in the onVisibilityChanged(boolean) override. I'm assuming here your timed images are for animation.

```
// start
if (renderLoop==-1) renderLoop = UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( this, 50, true );

// stop
if (renderLoop!=-1) 
{
  UiApplication.getUiApplication().cancelInvokeLater( renderLoop );
  renderLoop = -1;
}

//assumes your screen implements Runnable
public void run() {
   // do something cool
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry's `Timer` is very cheesy - it's just like a `Runnable` with `Thread.sleep()` inside. Very commonly for Blackberry, it contains lot of crap you don't actually need and doesn't contain things you **do** need.

I would dump the Timer and make a class specially for my needs:

```
abstract public class MyTimer extends Thread {
    private final Object waitobj = new Object();
    private volatile boolean running;
    private volatile boolean canceled;
    private final long due;

    public MyTimer setDelay(long delay) {
        long cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        due = cur + delay;
        return this;
    }

    public MyTimer setAlarmTime(long dueTimeMillis) {
        due = dueTimeMillis;
        return this;
    }

    synchronized void setIsRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    synchronized public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    synchronized public void cancel() {
        synchronized (waitobj) {
            canceled = true;
            waitobj.notify();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        setIsRunning(true);

        long cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long sleep = due - cur; 
        while (sleep > 0) {
            synchronized (waitobj) {
                waitobj.wait(sleep);
            }

            if (isCanceled()) return;
            cur = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sleep = due - cur; 
        }
        alarm();

        setIsRunning(false);
    }

    private boolean isCanceled() {
        return canceled;
    }

    abstract void alarm();
}
```

Then I would invoke it like this:

```
timer = new MyTimer() {
        void alarm() {
            // do cool things
        }
    };
timer.setDelay(10000).start();
```

If I need to cancel it I would do it like this:

```
if (timer.isRunning()) {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

or simply

```
timer.cancel();
```

*PS: Note `volatile` and `synchronized` things in MyTimer class.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're programming in Java with Swing, you have a method called *isRunning()* within the Timer Class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#isRunning%28%29

Regards

Comment: but there isn't isRunning() method in timer class on blackberry

Comment: BlackBerry uses Java-ME, so linking to Java 7 docs isn't so useful.